# SWT: Influence the detection of a Drag&Drop gesture (or: how to query the keyboard)

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, swt

I am at an SWT application where one can rearrange controls within a shell (or any `Composite` for that matter) via drag&drop. That's basically no problem, `DragSource`s and `DropTarget`s are all in place and listeners attached accordingly. I even implemented a custom `Transfer` type for the sake of exercise. Pretty straightforward.

But now the requirement is that a drag should only be initiated, if the ALT key is pressed while the drag gesture is performed, otherwise nothing should be done. (The ALT key is an example, could be CTRL as well.)

So far, I see or have thought about the following approaches. All of them either don't work or are ugly.

\1. Intercept and cancel the `DragDetect` event

The idea is to cancel the event if the ALT key is not pressed with `event.doit = false`.

```
        lblPos.addListener(SWT.DragDetect, new Listener() {
            public @Override void handleEvent(Event event) {
                if ((event.stateMask & SWT.ALT) == 0)
                    event.doit = false;     // XXX: doit will not be evaluated
            }
        });
```

However, that doesn't work. The `doit` flag is apparently not evaluated.

\2. Intercept and cancel the `DND.DragStart` event.

```
    class RowDragListener implements DragSourceListener {
        public @Override void dragStart(DragSourceEvent event) {
            if (/* ALT key not pressed */) 
                event.doit = false;
        }
        ...
    }
```

This has the opposite problem of appraoch 1. While the `doit` flag is properly evaluated and thus suitable to cancel the drag, there is no `stateMask` in the event that can be inspected for modifier keys. So the question arises, **how can I query the keyboard directly (without installing KeyUp/Down event handlers)? What is the current up/down state of the ALT key?**

\3. Combine 1 and 2

Inspect the `stateMask` in the `DragDetect` event, store the result somewhere, then react accordingly in the `DND.DragStart` event. This shouldn't be too hard, but I think it's ugly and should not be done this way. Instead of `DragDetect`, KeyUp/Down events could be captured and the last known state of the ALT key be stored.

\4. Override `Control.dragDetect(Event)` or `Control.dragDetect(MouseEvent)`

These methods ultimately create `DragDetect` events if they see the conditions for it fulfilled.

Check the event's `stateMask` and invoke the overridden method from the super class only if the desired modifier key is signalled. Problem here is, from the documentation it is not clear if this is the only code path that is treaded upon a drag gesture. In fact, these two methods are independent from each other (they don't invoke each other), so it's not even clear which one to override. These methods already are two separate ways to initiate a drag gesture. Who knows how many more ways are there? Overriding them all would be error prone, if possible at all, and certainly not clean.

So my questions are:
1. How would you do that? Any other ideas?
2. If approach 2 seems the most reasonable, how is the keyboard queried without resorting to event handlers?

(Sorry for the formatting of this post, i seem to be unable to grasp the syntax. Or maybe it's not my fault, who knows.)

**UPDATE**: There's one thing to note, which i noticed during the implementation. On Windows, ALT-Drag&Drop has the specific meaning of a link operation (as opposed to move or copy; cmp. DND.DROP_* constants). That's why, if you choose to use the ALT key in a similar fashion, be advised to include the following line at every reasonable occasion in the `DropTargetListener`.

```
 if (event.detail == DND.DROP_LINK) event.detail = DND.DROP_MOVE;
```

I have this in the `dragEnter`, `dragOver` and `dragOperationChanged` listener methods and this works quite fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to `SWT.DragDetect` event, check the state mask and create the drag source only if conditions are met. Then pass the event to the newly created drag source by calling `notifyListeneres()`. After drag finishes the drag source has to be disposed.

Here is a snippet where drag is initiated only if alt is pressed, and uses text as transfer:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());

    shell.addListener(SWT.DragDetect, new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            if ((event.stateMask & SWT.ALT) != 0) {
                final DragSource dragSource = new DragSource(shell, DND.DROP_MOVE);
                dragSource.addDragListener(new DragSourceAdapter(){
                    @Override
                    public void dragFinished(DragSourceEvent event) {
                        dragSource.dispose();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void dragSetData(DragSourceEvent event) {
                        event.data = "text";
                    }
                });
                dragSource.setTransfer(new Transfer[]{TextTransfer.getInstance()});
                dragSource.notifyListeners(SWT.DragDetect, event);

            }
        }
    });

    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea. I was not aware that DragSources can be managed so dynamically and can be triggered artificially. However, this is effectively like my approach #3, only that

Comment: ... only that the state of the modifier key is not stored in a boolean variable but in the fact that a DragSource exists.

Comment: @T-Bull yes, it is quite close to #3. But the idea of creating and initializing the `DragSource` later allows you to implement non standard cases, like dragging from normal or toolbar buttons when mouse is dragged out and other cases where even the `DragDetect` event doesn't work well.

Comment: I have settled for my case #3 now. I store a flag in a class which surrounds the label and drag source; that's not all too inelegant as I worried. An alternative would be to store the flag near the control using `Widget.setData()`. But I give you the points for the clever idea. I'll keep that in mind. It'll certainly come in handy at some time.